# Django: IndexError at /customerList/ tuple index out of range

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Can anyone help me with this. I don't understand this error

> IndexError at /customerList/
>   tuple index out of range

and it came from this code

`self.Customer = get_object_or_404(customer, name__iexact=self.args[0])`

I want to be able to do ListView some of the fields from two forms that is from customerForm (F_NAME, L_NAME) and buildingForm (B_USE, B_TYPE). Any help is very much is very very much appreciated. Thank u.

```
Traceback:
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,  **callback_kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  114.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
File "f:\iqgit\amon\amonsolution\solution\views.py" in get_queryset
  59.         self.Customer = get_object_or_404(customer, name__iexact=self.args[0])

Exception Type: IndexError at /customerList/
Exception Value: tuple index out of range
```

views.py

```
class customerListView(ListView):
    template_name = "customerList.html",
    model = customer
    context_object_name = "customer_list"

def get_queryset(self):
    self.Customer = get_object_or_404(customer, name__iexact=self.args[0])
    return building.objects.filter(Customer=self.Customer) 

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(customerListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['building_list'] = building.objects.all()

    return context
```

forms.py

```
class customerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    F_NAME = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput()
    L_NAME = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput()  
    EMAIL  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput()  
    ADD    = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput()
    class Meta:
        model = customer

class buildingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CUSTOMER     = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput()
    B_FLOORSPACE = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput()
    B_YEAR       = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput() 
    B_USE        = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=c.Use)
    B_TYPE       = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=c.Type)
    class Meta:
        model = building
        exclude = ('CUSTOMER',)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^customerList/',customerListView.as_view(), name= "customerList_view"),
```

customerList.html

```
...some of code...

{% for customer in customer_list %}
<tr class = {% cycle "row_even" "row_odd" %}>
<td>{{ customer.id }}</td>
<td class ="name"> <a href=" {% url customer_view customer.id %}">{{ customer.F_NAME }}&nbsp;{{ customer.L_NAME }}</a></td>
<td class ="b_use"> <a href=" {% url customer_view customer.id %}">{{ building.B_USE }}{{ building.B_TYPE }}</a></td>

...some of code...
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call a positional argument (`self.args[0]`) passed from the URL conf but you haven't added any positional arguments to your actual url. If you look at [how a request is processed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request), you will notice that:

> 4 . Once one of the [url] regexes matches, Django imports and calls the given view, which is a simple Python function. The view gets passed an HttpRequest as its first argument and any values captured in the regex as remaining arguments.

You aren't passing any arguments (neither positional or named) to your view so there is nothing in `self.args` or `self.kwargs`. You need to change your URL to something like:

```
url(r'^customerList/(\w+)/',customerListView.as_view(), name= "customerList_view"),
```

or ideally make use of [named arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) such as:

```
url(r'^customerList/(?P<name>\w+)/',customerListView.as_view(), name= "customerList_view"),
```

so that you can instead use `self.kwargs.get("name", None)`

Comment: thks @Timmy O'Mahony :)...got it change and read the ref. thks for pointing that:) but why do I get this error 404 error saying that page not found?

Comment: Because the string in `self.kwargs...` that is being used by `get_object_or_404` doesn't match a user with that name. Check that a user with that name actually exists in the DB by manually doing the query. Something like `Customer.objects.filter(name__iexact="bill")`.